# While Loop not integer

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've created this code to get unlimited values of integers, store them, and calculate the mean. It also does it in a squared format. My problem is, I created it so that the while loop only stops when the the number 0 is entered. However, I only put it there as a substitute, as it's the only way i could test the rest of the code to ensure it all works.

What I really want to do it have the while loop continue until the user provides input that is not an integer. Ive tried everything, using `hasNextint()` or `nextint` and so forth, what can I do?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class InputStats {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner TextIO = new Scanner(System.in);
    int inputNumber;     // One of the integers input by the user.
    int sum;             // The sum of all the integers.
    int count;           // The number of integers that have been entered.
    double mean;         // The mean value of the integers, rounded to 2 decimal places.
    int squarein;        // Value of squared number.
    int sumsquare;       // The sum of the squares of all the integers.
    double meansquare;   // The mean value of the squares of integers, rounded to 2 decimal places.

    /* Initialize the summation and counting variables. */
    sum = 0;
    count = 0;
    sumsquare = 0;
    meansquare = 0;

    /* Read and process the user's input. */
    System.out.println("Enter your first positive integer: ");
    inputNumber = TextIO.nextInt();

    while (inputNumber != 0) {
      sum += inputNumber;   // Add inputNumber to running sum.
      squarein =  inputNumber; //
      sumsquare = squarein * squarein; //square inputs
      count++;              // Count the input by adding 1 to count.
      System.out.println("Enter your next positive integer, or 0 to end: ");
      inputNumber = TextIO.nextInt();
    }

    /* Display the result. */
    if (count == 0) {
      System.out.println("You didn't enter any data!");
    } else {
      mean = ((double)sum) / count;
      meansquare = ((double)sumsquare) / count;

      TextIO.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Numbers entered: " + count + "\n");
      System.out.println("Sum: " + sum + "\n");
      System.out.println("Mean: " + mean + "\n");
      System.out.println("Sum Squares: " + sumsquare + "\n");
      System.out.println("Mean Square: " + meansquare + "\n");
    }
  } // end main()
} // end class InputStats
```

Comment: Have you heard of a `do...while` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read your values in as a string and then convert them to integers with Integer.parseInt(string);

That way you can use the following function to check if they're integers

```
public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
    try { 
        Integer.parseInt(s); 
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
        return false; 
    }
    // only got here if we didn't return false
    return true;
}
```

Your program would then look like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class InputStats {
    // *** I added this to help your while loop ***
    public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
        // check if a string is an integer, eg "10" is 10 but "w" is not an int
        try { 
            Integer.parseInt(s); 
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
            return false; 
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner TextIO = new Scanner(System.in);

        // *** I added this to store the input as a string first ***
        String input;        // The original string inputted by the user

        int inputNumber;     
        int sum;             
        int count;           
        double mean;         
        int squarein;        
        int sumsquare;       
        double meansquare;   

        sum = 0;
        count = 0;
        sumsquare = 0;
        meansquare = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter your first positive integer: ");

        // *** I changed this to .nextLine(); to get a string ***
        input = TextIO.nextLine();

        // *** I made this while it's an integer so it stops when it's a string ***
        while (isInteger(input)) {
            inputNumber = Integer.parseInt(input);
            sum += inputNumber;
            squarein =  inputNumber; 
            sumsquare = squarein * squarein; 
            count++;              
            System.out.println("Enter your next positive integer, or a non integer to end: ");

            // *** I changed this to .nextLine(); to get a string ***
            input = TextIO.nextLine();
        }

        if (count == 0) {
            System.out.println("You didn't enter any data!");
        }
        else {
            mean = ((double)sum) / count;
            meansquare = ((double)sumsquare) / count;

            // *** I removed this because it was no longer needed *** TextIO.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Numbers entered: " + count + "\n");
            System.out.println("Sum: " + sum + "\n");
            System.out.println("Mean: " + mean + "\n");
            System.out.println("Sum Squares: " + sumsquare + "\n");
            System.out.println("Mean Square: " + meansquare + "\n");
        }

    } // end main()

} // end class InputStats
```

Comment: @David Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

`hasNextInt()` should work

```
while(TextIO.hasNextInt()) {
   inputNumber = TextIO.nextInt();
   sum += inputNumber;
   squarein = inputNumber;
   sumsquare = squarein*squarein;
   count++;
   System.out.println("Enter your next positive integer: ");
}
```

Another thing, why do you call `TextIO.nextInt()` before your System.outs? It doesn't seem necessary and could possibly throw an error.

Comment: It still worked fine, but your right, it didn't seem necessary, so i've changed it.

What you've written here works, however, when i enter a alphanumeric or symbol, it comes up with an error rather than exiting the while loop

Answer (score 0):

Use a **boolean** flag. Set it to false initially and when user has inputted set it to true.

```
boolean userInputted = false;

while (!userInputted) {
.
.
.
// if user has inputted
    userInputted = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have the user input one line of text with numbers separated by commas and use `.split(",")` to separate into an array of strings, then loop through that array by the `.length` and apply `.trim()` to each string to remove trailing space, then use `Integer.parseInt(strarray[i])` to convert the strings to integers. And obviously put it all in a `try...catch` in case the user inputs badly formatted data.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a way to tell if what the user inputs is a number or something else.
Try something like this function.

```
    //Function to parse the input from provided scanner, and return null 
    //if input is not a number
    public static Integer parsedInputFrom(Scanner sc){
       String input= sc.next();
       Integer inputNumber=null;
       try{
              inputNumber = Integer.parseInt(input);
       } catch (NumberFormatException n){
           return null;
       }
       return inputNumber;
    }
```